# Runtime Error in my recursive program while printing 1 to n numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define N 100
 
int print(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
 
    print(n-1);
    cout<< n << " ";
}
 
// main function
int main()
{
    print(N);
    return 0;
}
```

//runtime error in this code while trying to run it please help and explain error is coming.

Comment: `print` doesn't always return. This is often fatal.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Either return an `int` from print like you say you are but don't, or change the function to return `void`.

Comment: @user4581301 _"This is often fatal"_ It's called _undefined behavior_, fatal indeed.

Comment: (not helping you with your issue, that have been solved in comments and answers) Also use `constexpr` not `#define` for `N`

Comment: _@Teja_ Always switch all warnings on when compiling, and fix them.

Comment: Warnings are the first line of defense against runtime errors. Compiler errors mean your source code could not be translated into executable code. Compiler warnings mean your code could be translated but probably doesn't describe the program behaviour you want.

Comment: To pick at nits:  Your function doesn't *return a value* when the `if` expression is false.  The function does return, but the value is undefined.

Comment: @user4581301 can you explain a little bit why print it is not always returning.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews n is decreasing in each call it should be zero after some calls and it should return right,but can you please explain why runtime error is coming??

Comment: @Tejasrinivas _"can you explain a little bit why print it is not always returning"_ Because you're missing a `return` statement outside of your `if() { }` block.

Comment: I wrote poorly. The function always returns, but it only returns a value if `in <= 0)` is true. The compiler may be generating code that depends on a value being returned even though the value is never used.

Comment: Does this make sense:  add `return n;` after the `cout` statement?

Comment: [Documentation for the concept of Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). UB is one of the most feared things in all programming because it can look like it works. You think the program worked. You tested it thousands of times. [And then the program crashes when you and your boss demonstrate it at Comdex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE). That's almost a good outcome considering what could happen. [A billion dollar spaceship could explode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `print` function can invoke *undefined behavior* because it may reach the end of function body without executing `return` statement.

The return type should be `void` if you won't use return value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define N 100
 
void print(int n) // change to void
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return; // remove 0
 
    print(n-1);
    cout<< n << " ";
}
 
// main function
int main()
{
    print(N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail a bit why this error is coming?

Comment: *it may reach* -- It [does reach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d054b40404e208b1)